# Does Maryam Namazie identify as a Muslim?

Tags: religion

In 2013, [an article in The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2013/dec/15/gender-segregation-unacceptable) described [Maryam Namazie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maryam_Namazie) as a Muslim:

> ...  it is clear that these appeasers have much to learn from Muslim women such as Sara Khan, Maryam Namazie ...

In 2015, [an article in the Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/student/news/muslim-students-from-goldsmiths-university-s-islamic-society-heckle-and-aggressively-interrupt-a6760306.html) described her as an ex-Muslim.

> ... ex-Muslim and feminist campaigner Maryam Namazie ...

Does Maryam Namazie identify as a Muslim?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about personal beliefs, which [cannot be empirically tested](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/621/politics-beliefs-and-motivations-questions-should-not-be-allowed-here).

Comment: @Oddthinking Sadiq is asking "according [to] her most recent proclamation of her religious views", not anything about her actual beliefs.

Comment: @DavePhD: That's not how the title read, before my edit. It isn't how the claims read either.

Comment: @Oddthinking My quote above was an exact quote from the original claim.  Anyone can see by looking at the edit history.

Comment: @DavePhD: Sorry, I may have been unclear. The (original) *title* asked directly about her religion, not her self-identity. The (existing) quoted text makes claims about her religion (not her self-identity). The OP's question text and my edited version both ask about her self-identity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [maryamnamazie.com](http://maryamnamazie.com/discrimination-violence-lie-heart-sharia-courts/), she is an ex-Muslim (December 2, 2016).

> The accusations were a clear attempt to discredit my evidence solely based on my atheism and being an ex-Muslim.

According to her official [twitter account](https://twitter.com/MaryamNamazie?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor) (verified), maryamnamazie.com is her official website. That means, the cited excerpt is part of an article published by her in December 2, 2016 on which she identified herself as an atheist and ex-Muslim.

Answer (score 4):

Maryam Namazie identifies as an ex-Muslim and an atheist.

Maryam Namazie is a founder of [The Council of Ex-Muslims of Britain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Council_of_Ex-Muslims_of_Britain), in 2007.

Their manifesto reads:

> We, non-believers, atheists, and ex-Muslims, are establishing or joining the Council of Ex-Muslims of Britain to insist that no one be pigeonholed as Muslims with culturally relative rights nor deemed to be represented by regressive Islamic organisations and ‘Muslim community leaders’.

An [Interview with The Londoner Magazine](http://thelondoner.eu/maryam-namazie-the-apostate-activist/) explains she is no longer a Muslim, but now is an atheist:

> Maryam Namazie is not afraid. But she has plenty of reasons to be very afraid. “I have received many calls over the years saying I will be decapitated or killed. I have also got threats from the Islamic regime of Iran, and I have had articles about me in the Iranian newspapers, where I am called ‘immoral’ and ‘corrupt’, things that are punishable by death out there,” she says. Her crime? She was raised a Muslim but turned her back on Islam to become an atheist.
>
> A gradual process still considered as a betrayal
>
> Maryam did not leave Islam overnight: “It was a gradual process and part of my political awakening against the regime in Iran, political Islam, and more generally all religions in power.”

As recently as 17 hours ago (as of time of writing), she [retweeted](https://twitter.com/DzFreeThinker/status/806269475628732416) a [documentary about her being an ex-Muslim](https://youtu.be/bupBgmtsNWU?t=1m47s).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49726/discussion-on-answer-by-oddthinking-does-maryam-namazie-identify-as-a-muslim).

Comment: This answer is useful because it indicates she was ex-Muslim before the date of the Guardian article.